# Web scraping performing search to authenticated endpoint fails (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, cheerio

I am trying to perform some web scraping to automate some data retrieval. The search I need to perform requires me to be logged in to my account, which I do have credentials for. I did a little testing and was able to get the data I needed if I manually assign my variables `dev` and `cookie` (cookie being the cookie I get from chrome developer tools request header when I make the request in the browser).

```
const dev = 'abcxyz';
const cookie  = '123456'

const searchOptions = {
    url:`https://someendpoint.com/device-detail?serial==${dev}`,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': `${cookie}`,
        'Host': 'someendpoint.com',
        'Referer': `https://someendpoint.com/device-detail`,
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    }

}

request(searchOptions, (err, res, body) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    const tabletID = $('#mdtDevice');
    console.log(tabletID.text());
})
```

in my `console.log(tabletID.text());` this does print out the serial number of the device scraped from the website, so everything works with this.

The problem is that I need to obviously get the cookie and devices without manually inputting them, to do so I've done this

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('fs');

main();

function login(){
    const loginOptions = {
        url: 'https://someendpoint.com/devices.php',
        auth: {
            username: 'xxx',
            password: 'xxx',
        }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(loginOptions, (err, res, body) => {
            if(!err && res.statusCode === 200){
                resolve(res.headers["set-cookie"].join());
            }else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}

async function main(){
   let rawCookie = await login();
   let cookie = rawCookie.slice(0, rawCookie.indexOf(';'));
   const devices = [];
   const path = './tvgs.txt';

    fs.createReadStream(path, 'utf8')
     .pipe(parse())
     .on('data', csvrow => {   
        devices.push(...csvrow);
     })
     .on('end', function() {
         search(devices, cookie);
     });
}

function search(devices, cookie){
    let tablets = [];
    console.log('devices', devices);
    console.log('cookie', cookie);

    for(const device of devices){  
        const searchOptions = {
            url:`https://someendpoint.com/device-detail??serial=${device}`,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Cookie': `${cookie}`,
                'Host': 'someendpoint.com',
                'Referer': `https://someendpoint.com`,
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
            }

        }

        request(searchOptions, (err, res, body) => {
            if(!err && res.statusCode === 200){
                const $ = cheerio.load(body);
                const tabletID = $('#mdtDevice').text();
                console.log(tabletID);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

the issue here is that when I `console.log(tabletID) here I get nothing back. If I`console.log('body')` the html I get back is the login page markup. If going through a browser the only time I get this login page when doing a search is if I have not logged in.

It's not clear to me why if my login is successful from my `login()` function which I confirmed by ensuring the cookie is set, am I not getting back the expected data when logging in programatically but if I hard code the cookie it works fine?

Again I thought maybe the cookie was not being set, but I can see the cookie if i `console.log(cookie)` at the top of my search function.

Could there be some oddballness going on with `search` function somehow firing before the `login` function finishes, even though I've got the call to `login` using `await`?

Comment: You've got `await login` but `login` is not `async`. My advice is to use await everywhere rather than callbacks.

Comment: After more testing it looks like the cookie i'm getting back in my response from `login` is not the cookie that I need to make my search request. Everything works if I make the request in the browser, copy that cookie into my code and then run it.

Comment: switching to puppeteer might help. Managing cookies is an advanced topic for stuff like this.

Comment: I switched to puppeteer and am able to handle exactly what I needed to. This is the first I heard of puppeteer, and I can see many more uses for it to automate a bunch of things I do at work. Thanks for your input!